# What is the form?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, definition

I'm studying linear and geometric algebra and I've asked myself always what is the form!

I had a lot of "form" expressions (such as: linear, bilinear, quadratic,...), but I don't get what it is.

Comment: It is used in different contexts. The name linear form means linear map. In the case of quadratic forms, "form" stands for "homogeneous polynomial".

Comment: It (almost) always means a homogeneous polynomial on some vector space $V$ to the underlying field $\mathbb{F}$, with other adjectives giving more restrictions.  The linear form means homogeneous of degree 1.  Bilinear means homogeneous of bidegree (1,1).  Quadratic form means homogeneous of degree 2.  Differential $k$-forms also obey this (except when you deal with mixed differential forms but by then you should know what you are doing).